# Getting Reboot instead of Shutdown on Linux Distros

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, shutdown, manjaro

**I've seen this problem before**, on the machine that i am having this bug i had Ubuntu and the same was going on but then i found a workaround that was to use `~# shutdown -P now` instead of only `~# shutdown now`, **but on this OS that doesn't work!**

I have tried both of those plus `~# poweroff` and `~# systemctl poweroff` also `systemctl --force poweroff` but all of them just do the same thing! (they reboot the machine). The only ones that don't do this is are `~# shutdown -H now` and `~# systemctl halt` but they don't complete turnoff the machine neither, just leave it frozen with the shutdown procedures screen.

All of this happen only when i have the **Ethernet** cable connected to the machine, but when i disconnect it manually the problem just vanishes! and that just blows my mind because i have already checked the Bios settings and everything **Wake up on LAN** related is disabled! Also as on some forums and threads suggested i have disabled the Wi-Fi radio but i know that is not the cause of the problem.

So why is all of this a problem? This laptop doesn't have a internal battery so have no choice but to trust my HDD to a script that detects when the pings to `google.com` fail so it can get shutdown automatically when the network is down, i can't accomplish it because of this problem that is related to my Ethernet connection, so why don't use **Wi-Fi** you say? for the purpuse that i am currently using it (a home server) that wouldn't make it more realiable because my Wi-Fi tends to fail sometimes.

Image when using ‘~# systemctl halt’
[image: When using systemctl halt]

Comment: Got back to ubuntu 16.04 and still have the same issue.

Comment: Tried ubuntu 18.04 and had the same issue. Gonna try with ubuntu 19

Comment: Got last night ubuntu 19.04 with the new Kernel like i used to have and same issue just that this time `sudo shutdown -P now` works again.