# Systemd reboots my PC instead of shutting it down

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, kde, reboot, systemd-journald

I just fresh installed Arch Linux and whenever I try to shutdown my PC, it just reboots. I've seen many similar issues ([here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/524015/getting-reboot-instead-of-shutdown-on-linux-distros)) but none of their solutions worked. Also, I have a feeling that the issue I'm facing is different. Because systemd is sending rebooting commands.
I've already tried:

- Different shutdown commands: `shutdown now -h`, `systemctl poweroff`,
  `systemctl --force poweroff`
- Disabling wake-on-lan / similar options
- Killing X and trying to shutdown

In fact, I noted that right before the system "turns off", the terminal prints the line `Started Reboot`. I just discovered that this have been discussed [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=203104), however no one brought a solution.
Here below is part of my `journalctl -b 1` and you can fine the lines: systemd-reboot.service: Succeeded and Started Reboot close to the end of the journal. Can someone help me?

```
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: Unmounted /boot.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: tmp.mount: Succeeded.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: Unmounted Temporary Directory (/tmp).
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: Stopped target Swap.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: Deactivating swap /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD10EZEX-22RKKA0_WD-WCC1S5355790-part1...
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:1f.2\x2data\x2d2\x2dpart1.swap: Succeeded.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-2-part1.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2dpartuuid-1b2952aa\x2d01.swap: Succeeded.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-partuuid/1b2952aa-01.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2did-wwn\x2d0x50014ee208f0cacb\x2dpart1.swap: Succeeded.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x50014ee208f0cacb-part1.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2did-ata\x2dWDC_WD10EZEX\x2d22RKKA0_WD\x2dWCC1S5355790\x2dpart1.swap: Succeeded.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD10EZEX-22RKKA0_WD-WCC1S5355790-part1.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: dev-sdb1.swap: Succeeded.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/sdb1.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-389bc3ae\x2d2f0b\x2d4fe1\x2d8c8a\x2d5a73ecd53ede.swap: Succeeded.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/389bc3ae-2f0b-4fe1-8c8a-5a73ecd53ede.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: home.mount: Succeeded.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: Unmounted /home.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1f356231\x2d99ac\x2d4451\x2da6b6\x2d491338f88a98.service: Succeeded.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: Stopped File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/1f356231-99ac-4451-a6b6-491338f88a98.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1f356231\x2d99ac\x2d4451\x2da6b6\x2d491338f88a98 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/sy>
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: Removed slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: Stopped target Local File Systems (Pre).
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service: Succeeded.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Succeeded.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-sysusers comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: Stopped Create System Users.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-remount-fs comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Succeeded.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: Reached target Shutdown.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: Reached target Final Step.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: systemd-reboot.service: Succeeded.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: Started Reboot.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-reboot comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-reboot comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: Reached target Reboot.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: Shutting down.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: Hardware watchdog 'iamt_wdt', version 1
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd[1]: Set hardware watchdog to 10min.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
Dec 12 16:25:47 Minami systemd-journald[283]: Journal stopped
```

Comment: Have you tried the `shutdown` command with no arguments? On my system, `shutdown` is a symbolic link to `systemctl` triggering `shutdown.target`

Answer (score 0):

for shutdown you seem to mix time and options order

```
   shutdown [OPTIONS...] [TIME] [WALL...]
```

so I expect your command of `shutdown now -h` to give "-h" as message for a shutdown (yet on my system it still would result in power down... but that likely can be changed. Thus try

```
shutdown --halt now
```

for better effect. The short form (on my system for `--halt` is `-H` with `-h` not being recognized.

However all this may not be the issue and it's a [kernel setting](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=244687) which needs to be passed by grub due to some hardware specifics:

```
xhcd_hcd.quirks=270336
```